# How to implement OneSignal web push in the next.js web application?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, onesignal, web-push

there is no exact answer to the above-asked question on the internet, so asked this question. I tried to implement OneSignal in my next.js web app but it returns various errors in development mode.

> What i did?
> I make a component and import react-onesignal to initialize OneSignal and write the below-shown code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
const initOneSignal = async () => {
    const OneSignal = (await import('react-onesignal')).default
    OneSignal.initialize('app id',options)

    useEffect(() => {
        initOneSignal()
      }, [])
  }


  export default initOneSignal;
```

Also, I put service worker files in the public folder and finally imported the above component inside `_app.js` on the pages folder
I got a lot of errors after doing the above process like **option is not defined**, **objects are not valid in react child** etc. What should I do to make the OneSignal work properly? Please give a working answer to this question which helps other junior developers like me to implement it.Thanks

Comment: where you declare `options` variable? why you import module in this way `(await import('react-onesignal')).default` ?

Comment: Using dynamic feature of next.js Basically options is not a variable it is the argument of intitialize method of react oneSignal as you can see it in its docs.If i am wronng then please show me the right way how to do it

Comment: Options is a variable that should contain your options, and in this case, is not defined...

Comment: Ok i will add the options,what about second error.And tell me one more thing that there is no return statement in the above function.will it work without return.can u make this a workable component?because i tried many ways to make this work but this didn't